# generic loop-unrolling with user-defined function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Recently I decided to make loop unroller. My function iterates from _Beg to _End(that are templates parameters) and calls function _func on each index:

```
template<size_t _Beg, size_t _End, typename _Func>
typename std::enable_if<_Beg < _End, void>::type
    for_r(_Func _func)
    {
        _func(_Beg);
        for_r<_Beg+1, _End>(_func);
    }
template<size_t _Beg, size_t _End, typename _Func>
typename std::enable_if<_Beg >= _End, void>::type
    for_r(_Func _func)
    {}
```

It works ok like this:

```
for_r<0, 10>([](size_t index){cout << index << endl;});
```

However, 'index' variable is known at compile time, so it would be logically to be possible to use 'index' as constant expression in lambda. Like this:

```
tuple<int, int, int, int> tpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
for_r<0, 4>([&](size_t index){cout << get<index>(tpl) << endl;});
```

But 'index' is variable, and it is not possible to pass it into lambda as constexpr. Is there some way to deal with it and implement logical behaviour without explicitly typing loop unrolling like this:

```
cout << get<0>(tpl) << endl << get<1>(tpl) << endl << get<2>(tpl) << endl << get<3>(tpl) << endl;
```

?

Comment: Brian, thank you very much for formatting my post :D. I was not on stackoverflow for much time and forgot how to do that(now remembered).

Comment: I'd trust the compiler, i.e. that it is able to determine that the lambda is called with values 0 to 3 and to inline those *if* *appropriate*. After all an important feature of lambdas is that they are local and that they allow aggressive optimization, in particular constant propagation. Have you compared the results (speed, generated machine code) of manual unrolling? That said, your code uses `_Reserved` identifiers for no reason at all, only making it harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 7 years passed and now we have nice features like C++17's *fold expressions* and C++20's *explicitly templated lambdas*, now it's possible to both write and use such "constexpr for"-like things easily. For example:

```
// Offsets std::integer_sequence by OFFSET
template <typename T, T OFFSET, T... IDXS>
constexpr std::integer_sequence<T, OFFSET + IDXS...> offset(
    std::integer_sequence<T, IDXS...>)
{
    return {};
}

// Calls templated operator() of given function object
// with INDEX template parameter from range [START; END)
template<std::integral T, T START, T END>
void for_constexpr_interval(auto iteration)
{
    if constexpr (START >= END)
        return;
    [&]<T... IDXS>(std::integer_sequence<T, IDXS...>) {
        (iteration.template operator()<IDXS>(), ...);
    }(offset<T, START>(std::make_integer_sequence<T, END - START>()));
}
```

Here inside `for_constexpr_interval` we use explicitly templated immediately invoked lambda to introduce template parameter pack `IDXS` through deduction from `std::integer_sequence` argument (created with the help of `offset` function on top of `std::make_integer_sequence` to represent `[START; END)` interval) while avoiding polluting namespace with unnecessary helper functions. This pack can now be directly used by fold expression without the need to resort to recursive instantiations. In that fold expression we call `iteration` function object's templated `operator()` with appropriate template parameter. The syntax `.template operator()` is needed to disambiguate that `operator()` denotes a *template*, so that, e.g., following `<` is not interpreted as "less than" sign.

It can be used like this:

```
std::tuple tpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
for_constexpr_interval<size_t, 0, 4>([&]<size_t INDEX>() {
    if constexpr (INDEX > 0)
        std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << std::get<INDEX>(tpl);
});
std::cout << std::endl;
for_constexpr_interval<int, -1, 2>([&]<int INDEX>() {
    std::cout << INDEX << std::endl;
});
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TonTa17ce)

Note that when passing function objects to `for_constexpr_interval` we yet again utilise explicitly templated lambdas. Also, it can be seen from the generated assembly that even at `-O1` optimisations calls in `main` get inlined, which happens at least for the latest GCC, Clang and MSVC. If needed, inlining can be forced by compiler-specific attributes/specifiers (on any combination of `for_constexpr_interval`, inner immediately invoked lambda, passed lambda), though *usually* such decisions are better left to compiler.

Finally, `for_constexpr_interval` can be changed/generalized/supplemented further, e.g. by allowing reverse traversal of indices, `STEP` (increment) argument or non-`std::integral` index types, but this will require more complex implementation for creating sequence of indices in inner lambda's argument (probably abandoning `std::make_integer_sequence` for custom alternative) and some care for floating-point indices.